# jQuery Datatables Intermittent issue with sort and search

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

Good evening,

I have been experiencing a weird intermittent error when sorting or searching: `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

The error is caused by the returned JSON string being empty. However this issue only happens from time to time when sorting or searching. (Usually when we input too fast or click several times on the sort column.)

**IMPORTANT**: This error only seems to be happening in hosted environment. Everything works in the localhost environment.

Datatables Server Side: https://pastebin.com/RiDdZLV1

Model:

```
<?php
  ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
  ini_set("log_errors", 1);
  ini_set("error_log", __DIR__."/errors.log");
  
  require(__DIR__."/Database/Conn.php");
  require(__DIR__."/Database/ServerDataTables.php");
  
  echo json_encode(
      SSP::complex( 
          $_POST, 
          "ws_persons", 
          "reservation_id", 
          array(
              array( 'db' => 'reservation_id', 'dt' => 0 ),
              array( 'db' => 'reservation_id', 'dt' => 1 ),
              array( 'db' => 'firstname', 'dt' => 2 ),
              array( 'db' => 'lastname','dt' => 3 ),
              array( 'db' => 'death_place', 'dt' => 4 ),
          ),
          "is_vet = 1", 
          null)
    );
?>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="/assets/css/app.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
         
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    
<script>

  $(function() {

   
    $('#resTable').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
          "url": "Model/DB_Reservations.php",
          "type": "POST",
          "data": {
              action: "loadAllRes",
          },
          "error": function (xhr, error, code){
            console.log(error);
            console.log(code);
            console.log(xhr);
          },
        }
    });
  });


</script>

<table id="resTable" class="table dt-responsive nowrap" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; width: 100%;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Reservation #</th>
        <th>Veteran</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use your browser developer tools to check what exactly is returned by the PHP called via AJAX. most probably you have a warning/notice there that is breaking the json syntax

Comment: I verified the console and network reponse. No errors were thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of debugging I found the issue. Datatables is having trouble reading certain characters in the database.

Thus, adding `$db->exec("set names utf8");` after the connection inside the Datatables Server Side script fixed my issue.

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21242/invalid-json-response-when-adding-some-utf-8-characters